# How To Fire Addon Method With Cron Job

Tags: add-on, add-on-development, cron, action, curl

EE 5.3.0

I have a feature that compares and updates data from different services using various APIs. I set it up to trigger based on url ACT id and a key. The script works fine and now I want to make it run automatically two times per day.

To do this I wanted to use a cron job. My webserver is HostGator, dedicated server, which has a cron job section in the cPanel. I've set up a test to run every minute and return the results to me via email. This is not working and I have changed the command to many different things, none of which work.

The script is set up to return a reply of `testing` when there is the ACT ID and the key of `test` in the url, so `https://www.domain.com/ACT=42&key=test` prints `testing`.

I've tried setting this up as a cron job using cURL in several different ways.

`curl --silent --compressed https://www.domain.com/ACT=42&key=test`

`curl -s "https://www.domain.com?ACT=42&key=test"`

`curl "https://www.domain.com/ACT=42&key=test"`

Nothing is sending an email so I have no idea if this is even working.

When I contacted HostGator support the rep gave me a bunch of links on how to set up a cron job, which didn't help. I've done this before on a shared HostGator server for an import addon and it worked fine, ran the script, got the email, etc. But for this I'm not getting anything and I'm at a bit of a loss.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After confirming your extension is installed with module.

Have you registered your action in table `exp_actions`? If no, then first register your action with respected method name. If yes, then make sure method name which you've specified in the `exp_actions` should be declared in the `mod.plugin_name.php`. And check with just echoing sample text. After confirming this you can go for setting up CRON.

And, that method is accessible with `website_url/?ACT=your_action_id`. Same url you've to add it into the CRON job and check accordingly.

Try by setting your CRON URL by below way:-

```
wget https://domain_name.com/index.php?ACT=action_id &> /dev/null
```

I hope it will works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Harsh. I'm not sure what the issue is with this. It is possible the functions simply aren't returning any data in a way that the cron would recognize and send an email -- I have it printing out a series of responses based on the results of the feature, and while these work on the page I'm not getting anything back from the cron. I readily admit I'm not a skilled developer in Linux task scheduling.